# Any solution like google-fonts for some fonts

Tags: fonts, font-face, cufon, google-font-api

can you help and advise any solution for my fonts on web-site: intro and helvetica light. I'm using cufon and it causes some problems. They aren't icluded in google fonts collection, so is there any free alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica Light is available from [Fonts.com's webfont service](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica/light/web-font) which functions the same as Google fonts. Fonts.com does have a free plan that includes 3,000 fonts, but I don't think Helvetica Light is included in that plan. The cheapest plan is $10/month with discounts for longer-term agreements.

It's unlikely that you'll find any free service (legally) offering Helvetica Light or other commercial fonts.